# How do I add a comment to a post through the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, script, api-v2.2, authentication, comments

I want to add an comment to a specific post so, how do I get its ID and how do I authorize it. I want it to done through the Stack Exchange API interface.

Answer (score 1):

1. For posting comments, you need a request key for your application:

> Applications should be registered on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) to get a request key. Request keys grant more requests per day, and are necessary for using access_tokens created via [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).

2. You need to [enable write access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) for your application. I think you can use this question as registered Stack Apps post.
3. Get an access token with write access, by following the steps described in [Authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).
4. To find the ID of a post, click the share link and copy the first number after `/q/` or `/a/`. The ID of your question is 8833:

[image]

5. Use the [`/posts/{id}/comments/add` method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment) to add a comment. You'll have to add the request key and access token obtained above. Be sure to set the `preview` parameter to false; otherwise, it looks like it creates a comment but doesn't actually do it.

You can use posts in the [API sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51812/295232) or one of your own questions to test; remember that comments cause notifications and you don't want to needlessly ping users. Good luck!

Comment: When I register for this post it says this error Post should be tagged [app] or [script]

Comment: For the time being, you can add either tag to the question. It's not officially an [app] or [script] post, but who cares ...

Comment: Now it says this kind of error                                                                                             {
  "error_id": 407,
  "error_message": "User does not have permission to comment on this post",
  "error_name": "write_failed"
}

Comment: Then you did everything right (not a small feat!) except that (and I should have noticed that upfront) don't have the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to comment, except on your own posts and answers to your questions.

Comment: I am the owner of this post right? Ideally I should able to add a comment. But it says I not have permission to comment on this post...  Wait a sec I am the owner of this post

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Not sure why that wouldn't work ...